# Проблема с проверкой ввода символа enter с помощью nodejs raw stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я не могу проверить ввод символа `enter`. Пытался использовать `if (key.charCodeAt (0) === 13) console.log ('ENTER');` после того, как я увидел ту же проблему с [backspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237468/trouble-with-checking-for-backspace-character-with-nodejs-raw-stdin?target=_blank), и она работает для меня, но я не могу понять, что не так с unicode `enter`? потому что `backspace`, `space` и `ctrl-c` работает отлично. Я также пробовал `\ue006` и `\ue007`, и они также не сработали.

```
console.clear();

var BACKSPACE = '\u0008';
var CTRL_C = '\u0003';
var ENTER = '\u2386';
var SPACE = '\u0020';

var stdin = process.stdin;

stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

stdin.on('data', (key) => {

    if (key === 'q') process.exit();

    if (key === ENTER) console.log('ENTER');

});

stdin.setRawMode(true);
```

Comment: Почему у вас `ENTER` это `'\u2386'`? И какая ос?

Comment: @AlexeyTen увидел [тут](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2386/index.htm) и не только, а ОС у меня - Windows 10 x64

Comment: О боже. Это не enter с клавиатуры, а иконка входа 

Comment: @AlexeyTen Я это тоже увидел) Просто была отчаянная попытка использовать это ибо `\ue006` и `\ue007` не подошли

Comment: Ну вообще-то enter всегда был 13, т.е. `\u000d`, хотя может в винде еще перед ним `\u000a` по традиции ставят https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: @AlexeyTen Напишите это как ответ и я его отмечу как ответ, который мне помог. Оказывается проблема была в том, что я всё это время интерпретировал `enter` как `\n`, а надо было как `\r`. Спасибо вам огромное